# add value to local variable oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql

```
DECLARE 
var1 INTEGER :=0;
var2 INTEGER :=0;
BEGIN

SELECT DISTINCT
<whatever here>

CASE
WHEN trunc(thisDate) - TRUNC(thatDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN var1+1
WHEN trunc(thisDate2) - TRUNC(thatDate2) BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN var2+1 
ELSE 0 
END 

FROM
<Rest of query here>
```

basically what I want to be able to do is to add 1 to the local variable then print out the value of that variable as part of my select statement using a count (or sum of the count) or something everytime the difference in the ages falls within those categories

I'm not sure how to add to the local variable basically.

Comment: I suspect that the OP actually wants an incrementing value for each range. SQL Server allows this by letting the variable be assigned a new variable for each row. I suspect that he is trying to reproduce this functionality.

Comment: Very good spot, @Allan (I've messed up when +1 you comment -- sorry). _Dan_, maybe you should provide some sample _input_ data and the expected outcome.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    sum(CASE WHEN trunc(thisDate) - TRUNC(thatDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + var1,
    sum(CASE WHEN trunc(thisDate2) - TRUNC(thatDate2) BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + var2
    into var1, var2
FROM
<Rest of query here>
```

Comment: check that your else condition will return `var1` instead of `0`

Comment: @Aramillo I'm not sure I understand your comment. I suppose I only forgot to sum

Comment: sorry my bad english, but what i mean is that in case that condition is false you return `0 + var2`, and OP wants only `0`

Comment: @Aramillo I think that after adding a sum it's not actual anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try analytic functions

```
BEGIN
SELECT DISTINCT
<whatever here>

sum(CASE
WHEN trunc(thisDate) - TRUNC(thatDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN 1
end) over() var1,
sum(CASE
WHEN trunc(thisDate2) - TRUNC(thatDate2) BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN 1 
END) over() var2

FROM
<Rest of query here>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a comment by Allan, maybe you are looking for something like than instead:

```
SELECT V.*,
    case when t1 is not null then
          count(t1) over (ORDER BY n ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
         when t2 is not null then
          count(t2) over (ORDER BY n ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
         else
          0
    end varX
    FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT

    <whatever here>

    ROWNUM n,
    CASE WHEN trunc(thisDate) - TRUNC(thatDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN 1 END t1,
    CASE WHEN trunc(thisDate) - TRUNC(thatDate) BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN 1 END t2


    FROM
    <Rest of query here>

    ) V
```

Some example for you to check if this is what you are looking for: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2de0d/2

The inner query is basically yours, plus

- a `ROWNUM` column (maybe not necessary if you somehow `ORDER BY` your rows)
- a marker set to 1 if the row is in the first range,  `NULL` otherwise
- a marker set to 1 if the row is in the second range,  `NULL` otherwise

The outer query use the analytic function `COUNT() OVER(...)` to respectively count the numbers of markers between the current row and the first of the result set. The row number `n` is used here. Replace that by something more relevant if your data are already ordered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can *update* some variable while executing a query. All you can do is *fetch* the result value into some variable.

Slight variation over Multisync's answer, using `COUNT` instead of `SUM`:

```
SELECT 
    count(CASE WHEN trunc(thisDate) - TRUNC(thatDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN 1 END) ,
    count(CASE WHEN trunc(thisDate2) - TRUNC(thatDate2) BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN 1 END)
    into var1, var2
FROM
<Rest of query here>
```

This will actually return a one-row result with the count of values is the first range in the first column, and the count of values in the second range in the second column. Using the `INTO var1,var2` clause, PL/SQL will implicitly fetch those values into your local variables.